# How to use hidden field to store data model in wicket

Tags: wicket

I have a entity, name Product.It have two property is unit (byte) and unitName(String). unit property is mapped on database. Ex: 0:Kg ; 1:g;.... I want when input a valid unit, unit property is stored; unless, it save to unitName

**Product**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "product_id")
private int productId;

@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;

@Column(name = "unit")
private Byte unit;

@Transient
private String unitName;
}
```

In unit text field, I use a UnitConvert

**UnitConvert**

```
public class UnitConverter implements IConverter<Byte> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4798262219257031818L;

public UnitConverter() {
}

@Override
public Byte convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) {
    return Text.isEmpty(value) ? 0 : UtilCommon.getTaniCode(value);
}

@Override
public String convertToString(Byte value, Locale locale) {
    return (value == null || value==0 ) ? "" : UtilCommon.getTaniName(value);
}
}
```

I only think about HiddenField to do that, but I don't know how to do that.
Someone know how to use or anything can help me. Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.HiddenField` as any other form field in wicket. So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understood you want to save the input of a `Model` to a different database property depending on certain checks before hand. You can do that in your `Form.onSubmit()` method.

A very simple implementation could look like this:

```
    public ProductPanel(String id, final IModel<Object> productModel) {
    super(id, productModel);
    // we're putting the productModel into the constructor. 
    // Therefore it's guaranteed to be detached
    // -> it's okay to have it with final modifier.

    IModel<String> formModel = Model.of("");

    Form<String> form = new Form<String>("form", formModel) {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            super.onSubmit();
            String productName = getModelObject();

            Object realProduct = productModel.getObject();
            if (isAcceptableUnit(productName)) {
                realProduct.setUnit(parseUnit(productName));
            } else {
                realProduct.setUnitName(productName);
            }

            layer.saveProduct();
        }
    };
    add(form);

    TextField<String> productName = new TextField<String>("textField", formModel);
    form.add(productName);

}

private boolean isAcceptableUnit(String productName) {
    // your logic to determine if it's okay to cast to byte here...
    return true;
}

private byte parseUnit(String productName) {
    // your logic to parse the String to byte here...
    return 0;
}
```

Some additional comments since I'm uncertain if the code snippets you provided are just for simplicity or actually code pieces:

You should try to avoid declaring your db object `Serializable`. Should you use normal `Model` objects to save your DTOs wicket will actually serialize them and you won't be able to do anything with them (well with hibernate at least).
Database object should use `LoadableDetachableModel` and save the primary key to load the entity in the `load()` method of it.
This would enable you now to work directly on those objects by using `CompoundPropertyModel` etc (which has it's pros and cons which I will not explain in detail here).

Still in your case I would add an `Model<String>` to the form and let the server decide how the input should be handled and mapped to the actual domain object.